# pyQT5 - Adding records to a SQLlite table using QTableView

Tags: pyqt5

I'm doing first steps using the model-view architecture and I created a simple program (see the code below) to load data from a SQLite table to display in a form.
I used QSqlTableModel and QTableView and the code works as expected showing data selected from the specified table.

Now I would need to add rows to the SQLite table using the QTableView and I'm wondering whether there's a way for doing it "spreadsheet-wise", meaning having an empty row after last row in the QTableView to be filled with values and then inserting the new record in the SQLlite table through QSqlTableModel.

If not, which is the suggested way to manage such case? Using a QPushButton to trigger the insertion of new record ?

Thanks for any help

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView,QWidget,QMessageBox, QMainWindow
from connect_SQLITE import Database
from RisorseInterneUi import Ui_Form

class MainWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)       
    self.model.setTable("tb_RisorseInterne")
    self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
    self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "CDL")
    self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Desc_CDL")
    self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Tipo")
    self.model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "Desc_2")
    self.model.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, "Costi")
    self.model.setHeaderData(5, Qt.Horizontal, "Troncone")
    self.model.setHeaderData(6, Qt.Horizontal, "BarraUtile")
    self.model.setHeaderData(7, Qt.Horizontal, "SovrametalloPerTaglio")
    self.model.setHeaderData(8, Qt.Horizontal, "CambioUtensile")
    self.model.setHeaderData(9, Qt.Horizontal, "TempoCSAutomatico")
    self.model.setHeaderData(10, Qt.Horizontal, "TempoRiposizCreSecPass")
    self.model.setHeaderData(11, Qt.Horizontal, "TempoRiposizCreCaricMANUALE")
    self.model.setHeaderData(12, Qt.Horizontal, "NrGiriMax-RPM")
    
    self.model.select()
    
    self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
    self.tableView.setSelectionMode(QTableView.SingleSelection)
    self.tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectItems)
    


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Well, that is theoretically doable, but not simple. The problem is that spreadsheets, due to their nature, consider empty cells as a normal state with an arbitrary number of rows/columns. You might need to add support for data checking and eventually ignore all final rows with null entries, but what should happen if users try to insert records after leaving a empty rows? A simpler possibility could be to add a new row when the user doubleclicks outside any existing row and immediately begin editing, and eventually add support for the tab/return keys when finishing editing of the last item.

Comment: A spreadsheet-style empty row seems much more suited to free-form tables. For a table with a fixed structure, a separate widget with dedicated form fields may be more appropriate. As a user, I would much rather have the latter if I had to add/edit lots of records on a regular basis. Entering everything via tiny edit fields crammed onto a single row just isn't very user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL-based views are not intended to be used as a spreadsheet, which is more of a "free-form" way of a model view.

The main issue is that SQL expects a more strict layout for which records respect the column layout (and, possibly, their data types) and have a defined count.

Spreadsheets do not work like this: you can set arbitrary data on each index, and the row or column count doesn't really matter for the purpose.

That said, while I completely agree with [ekhumoro's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71354020/pyqt5-adding-records-to-a-sqllite-table-using-qtableview#comment126125830_71354020) (it's usually better to have a separate UI for data editing and insertion), there are occasions for which fast/direct insertion might be preferred for UI consistency and ease of use.

Creating new *batches* of rows or columns is clearly not a viable solution:

- changing the column layout of a database is not immediate, and can become extremely (and unnecessarily) complex;
- adding a bunch of rows is pointless: you'd need to check if each newly added row has valid data, and eventually decide whether to ignore it or not, but what if a previously ignored row gets edited with valid data?

Considering the above, a possible solution is to create a system that allows easy insertion of new record. To achieve this, there are various possible approaches, but, first of all you need to create a proper method that actually adds a new record and begins editing:

```py
class AddRecordTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def addRecordAndEdit(self):
        self.setCurrentIndex(QtCore.QModelIndex())
        row = self.model().rowCount()
        self.model().insertRow(row)
        firstColumn = self.horizontalHeader().logicalIndex(0)
        index = self.model().index(row, firstColumn)
        self.setCurrentIndex(index)
        if index.flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable:
            self.edit(index)
            # we assume that the new index is always the last row, so we
            # scroll to the bottom no matter what; if we implement a "fake
            # item" to add new records, this will ensure that it will always
            # be visible when editing begins
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: 
                self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(
                    self.verticalScrollBar().maximum()))
```

Now, we could just call that method when some button gets clicked, but we may also consider two important possibilities:

- the user uses <kbd>Tab</kbd> when finished editing on the *last* item;
- the user double-clicks below the last (visible) row;

So, we can do that by properly implementing the related methods:

- [`closeEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#closeEditor) gets called whenever a non-persistent editor loses focus due to a <kbd>Tab</kbd> keypress, and we could eventually call `addRecordAndEdit` if we know that the *closing* index is the last visible row/column of the table;
- [`mouseDoubleClickEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#mouseDoubleClickEvent) is called every time the user double-clicks the viewport contents, so if we know that there's no valid index at that point we could decide to create a new record;

```py
class AddRecordTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def addRecordAndEdit(self):
        # as above...

    def _lastColumn(self):
        if not self.model():
            return -1
        return self.horizontalHeader().logicalIndex(
            self.model().columnCount() 
            - self.horizontalHeader().hiddenSectionCount() - 1)

    def _lastRow(self):
        if not self.model():
            return -1
        return self.verticalHeader().logicalIndex(
            self.model().rowCount() 
            - self.verticalHeader().hiddenSectionCount() - 1)

    def closeEditor(self, editor, hint):
        if hint == QtWidgets.QAbstractItemDelegate.EditNextItem:
            current = self.currentIndex()
            if (current.row() == self._lastRow() and 
                current.column() == self._lastColumn()):
                    super().closeEditor(
                        editor, QtWidgets.QAbstractItemDelegate.NoHint)
                    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.addRecordAndEdit)
                    return
        super().closeEditor(editor, hint)

    def canAddRowFromEventAtPos(self, pos):
        # we will need this later...
        lastColumn = self._lastColumn()
        if lastColumn < 0:
            # this should not happen...
            return False

        lastRow = self._lastRow()
        rect = self.visualRect(self.model().index(lastRow, lastColumn))
        return rect.isNull() or pos.y() >= rect.bottom()

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)
        if (event.button() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton or 
            self.indexAt(event.pos()).isValid()):
                return

        if self.canAddRowFromEventAtPos(event.pos()):
            self.addRecordAndEdit()
```

Now, there's a little catch here: if the view size is just as tall as the current rows, there is no place to double-click to add another item.

What we need is to add some more vertical space so that a "fake item" could be shown, allowing the user to double-click it in order to add the new record.

To achieve that, I've implemented a further subclass (but you may probably choose to merge it into one). This adds a further vertical "margin" to the view, and also paints a fake item that will show a hint of what could be done: as long as you double-click that "fake item", you will add a new record.

```py
class AddRecordTableViewFakeItem(AddRecordTableView):
    _addRect = None
    _hoverAdd = False
    def canAddRowFromEventAtPos(self, pos):
        # override for AddRecordTableView, we can only add new records as long
        # as the event pos is within the "add rect" boundaries
        return self._lastColumn() >= 0 and pos in self.addRect()

    def updateGeometries(self):
        super().updateGeometries()
        self._addRect = None

        # increase the maximum value of the vertical scroll bar in order to allow
        # scrolling *beyond* the last row
        viewHeight = self.viewport().size().height()
        vlength = self.verticalHeader().length()
        sectionSize = self.verticalHeader().defaultSectionSize()
        if (self.verticalScrollMode() == self.ScrollPerItem and 
            viewHeight < vlength + sectionSize):
                extend = 1
        elif viewHeight < vlength + sectionSize:
            extend = min(sectionSize, vlength + sectionSize - viewHeight)
        else:
            # the viewport is tall enough, ignore
            return

        self.verticalScrollBar().setMaximum(
            self.verticalScrollBar().maximum() + extend)

    def scrollContentsBy(self, dx, dy):
        super().scrollContentsBy(dx, dy)
        if dy:
            self._addRect = None
        if (self.verticalScrollMode() == self.ScrollPerItem and
            0 < self.verticalScrollBar().value() == self.verticalScrollBar().maximum()):
                self.verticalHeader().setOffset(
                    self.verticalHeader().offset() 
                    + self.verticalHeader().defaultSectionSize())
                self.viewport().scroll(0, -self.verticalHeader().defaultSectionSize())

    def viewportEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() in (event.HoverEnter, event.HoverMove, event.HoverLeave):
            addRect = self.addRect()
            hoverAdd = event.pos() in addRect
            if self._hoverAdd != hoverAdd:
                self._hoverAdd = hoverAdd
                self.viewport().update(addRect)
        return super().viewportEvent(event)

    def addRect(self):
        if self._addRect is None:
            lastRow = self._lastRow()
            if lastRow < 0:
                y = 0
            else:
                vr = self.visualRect(self.model().index(lastRow, 0))
                y = vr.y() + vr.height()
            if self.horizontalScrollBar().value() < self.horizontalScrollBar().maximum():
                width = self.viewport().width() - 1
            else:
                lastColumn = self._lastColumn()
                right = (self.horizontalHeader().sectionPosition(lastColumn)
                    + self.horizontalHeader().sectionSize(lastColumn))
                width = right - self.horizontalHeader().offset() - 1
            self._addRect = QtCore.QRect(0, y, width, 
                self.verticalHeader().defaultSectionSize() - 1)
        return self._addRect

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        super().enterEvent(event)
        self.viewport().update()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        super().leaveEvent(event)
        self.viewport().update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        model = self.model()
        if not model or not self.underMouse():
            return
        r = self.addRect()
        if r.y() > event.rect().bottom():
            return
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self.viewport())
        qp.setRenderHint(qp.Antialiasing)
        qp.translate(.5, .5)
        if not self._hoverAdd:
            color = self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text)
        else:
            color = self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Text)
        color.setAlphaF(color.alphaF() * .75)
        qp.setPen(color)
        qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
        qp.drawRoundedRect(r.adjusted(1, 1, -1, -1), 2, 2)
        fm = self.fontMetrics()
        text = fm.elidedText('Double click here to add record', QtCore.Qt.ElideRight, 
            r.width() - 4 - fm.horizontalAdvance(' ') * 2)
        qp.drawText(r, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, text)
```

Note: this has only been tested with a basic, simple model. Most importantly, I didn't test it with *large* models that will add records on [`fetchMore()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore) (which usually defaults to 255 records).